# What is the fieldname to store a birthday for a contact entry?

Tags: android

As you can know, you can store data against a contact on Android phones. I am wondering if there is a standard name to store a birthday against a contact?

[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/7673/screenbirthday.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/7673/screenbirthday.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Birthday details are stored in the Event table (Android 2.0). You can check the java docs  [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.html) for more details.